# Threading : Running USB keyboard on ARM cortex A8

Tags: embed, embedded-linux

I am new to the Emebedded Linux. I want to use my USB keyboard using threading.. I know the concept of the threading but i want to know how i can detect it using the concept of threading. ?

Comment: rephrase the question please, it's impossible to understand.

Comment: Can you please explain whether you want to write an application program or a device driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wish to use non-blocking I/O to read the keyboard, you can use a thread which does a blocking read and signals your main thread (or sets a flag which it can poll) when input is available.

In addition to blocking, you may have to contend with a default setting to line mode.

A common choice for polling or responding too single characters in a single threaded program is to change the terminal mode settings - see the man pages for termios, stty, etc.  You will however need to change them back if your program exits.

Another option would be to skip the whole terminal infrastructure and read the input events directly through /dev/input/.  Or at an extreme you could skip the USB HID driver and write your own kernel driver for USB keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you have a embedded linux board and now you want to connect a USB keyboard and use it with applications on the embedded linux board? If this is correct then you dont need to do anything with threading. What you need to do is have drivers installed for that keyboard. For that you should look into the kernel build config to see if the USB keyboard drivers (HID drivers) are enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of following based on your requirement :

1. blocking I/O
2. non-blocking I/O

For non-blocking I/O, try Multi-threading based approach. For blocked I/O, try epoll() system call based approach.

Regarding the method to detect the keyboard, you can try the following :

1. Use the file /proc/bus/input/devices to detect on the devices, but it does not get updated until you reboot in certain systems.
2. Detect using /dev/input/eventN and the ioctl() call to detect the event bits. The event interface is very useful as it exposes the raw events to userspace.